# Why are graphics rendered as MathML when I set $PrePrint = MathMLForm?

Tags: graphics

For external usage, I set output in `MathMLForm` by using `$PrePrint=MathMLForm`

Everything goes well but makes graphics rendered in `MathMLForm` as well. How could I make graphics rendered as image?

> [image]

---

New added:

Thanks for @Kuba, But I am facing another problem when execute script like:

```
Table[Plot[f[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, Exclusions -> {1/f[x] == 0}], 
      {f, {Tan, Cot, Csc, Sec}}]
```

The final result is not a type of graphics, but it contains graphics. So it rendered in MathML finally.

> [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**:

```
$PrePrint =.;

$PrePrint = With[{expr = #}, 
                 If[MemberQ[expr, _Graphics | _Graphics3D | _Graph, {0, ∞}], 
                            expr, 
                            MathMLForm[expr]]] &;
```

---

**Before edit**:

```
$PrePrint =.;

$PrePrint = If[MatchQ[#, _Graphics | _Graphics3D | _Graph], #, MathMLForm[#]] &;
```

Is this what you are after?

Comment: Thanks! @Kuba. This is exactly what i want.

Comment: Hi @Kuba, I am facing another problem when using the script. Would you please take a look ? thanks!

Comment: Done. You replied so fast as I didn't finish the update :p

Comment: thanks again, I added MatchQ statement for graphics only scenario. And it's all right now.

Comment: @Michael not needed but thanks for paying attention, I have to get a coffee :) Added `{0, \[Infinity]}`