# How to speed up accidental large output?

Tags: syntax, argument-patterns, optional-arguments, parsing

From time to time I accidentally let large expressions like `RandomReal[1., {10^5, 10, 10}]` reach the front end. The computation of the result is quite fast (`AbsoluteTiming` gives 0.0896609), but the kernel will still take a very long time, just to finally display the 'large output' widget.

Sometimes I can abort the "output-computation" to avoid waiting, but I cannot know when the actual computation that I *want* to finish ends.

Is there a way to have the front-end do something different on large output? Maybe applying something like `Short` to large results instead of the 'large output' widget, though `Short` also seems to be slow. `Dimensions` might be preferable.

Are there any hooks for this?

Answer (score 2):

This can be of help

```
$PrePrint = If[ByteCount[#] > 10^6, Shallow[#, 1], #] &
```

Maybe something more fancy is needed to pass larger `Graphics`, it is up to you.

You can put it init.m analogously to: [What bug fixes can be implemented in init.m?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30599/5478)

Comment: Unfortunately, this causes weird and hard-to-track error messages with say `Plot3D`: After setting this, e.g. `Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotPoints -> 100, 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic]` will print an error message saying "Skeleton is not a Graphics3D primitive or directive"

Comment: @masterxilo That is what I was anticipating in the line below the code block. You can try to adjust it, analogously to: [Why are graphics rendered as MathML when I set $PrePrint = MathMLForm?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48397/5478)